# Groovy's StreamingTemplateEngine throws MissingPropertyException when rendering PHP template

Tags: groovy

in a Jenkins Pipeline we deploy a PHP site which has config files in PHP - format. Now we want to use the StreamingTemplateEngine for creating these config Files with different content (lets say different databases for dev- and prod stages).
In PHP variables are prefixed with $ - signs which now collides with the $ - sign marked placeholders from the StreamingTemplateEngine. That means it throws an exception when reaching a PHP Variable, that should be left as it is.

I think an example makes it more clear:

Template File test.php.template:

```
<?php
$my_php_config_variable = "${StreamingTemplateEnginePlaceholder}"
?>
```

Groovy Code Snippet:

```
import groovy.text.StreamingTemplateEngine

def placeholders = [
    "StreamingTemplateEnginePlaceholder": "SOME_VALUE",
]
def templateContent = new File('test.php.template').text

def engine = new StreamingTemplateEngine()
def configContent = engine.createTemplate(templateContent).make(placeholders).toString()

println configContent
```

Now the resulting configContent string should be:

```
<?php
$my_php_config_variable = "SOME_VALUE"
?>
```

But the engine throws this Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" groovy.text.TemplateExecutionException: Template execution error at line 2:
         1: <?php
     --> 2: $my_php_config_variable = "${StreamingTemplateEnginePlaceholder}"
         3: ?>

    at SimpleGroovyScript.run(SimpleGroovyScript.groovy:10)
    at SimpleGroovyScript.main(SimpleGroovyScript.groovy)
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: my_php_config_variable for class: groovy.tmp.templates.StreamingTemplateScript1
    ... 2 more
```

saying, "$my_php_config_variable" is missing in the placeholder map.

Now our questions are:

1.) Can the PHP vars in the template somehow be marked to be left as is for the TemplateEngine?

OR

2.) Can the Engine somehow simply ignore "missing" placeholders in the placeholder map and leave the strings as is?

Thx in advance for every hint!
T0mcat

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape `$` in your template:

```
<?php
\$my_php_config_variable = "${StreamingTemplateEnginePlaceholder}"
?>
```

If you want to use `StreamingTemplateEngine` to render this template you will have to update your code a little bit. `StreamingTemplateEngine` leaves escape characters in rendered output, so you will have to replace `\$` with `$` in the rendered template:

```
import groovy.text.StreamingTemplateEngine

def placeholders = [
  "StreamingTemplateEnginePlaceholder": "SOME_VALUE",
]
def templateContent = new File('test.php.template').text

def engine = new StreamingTemplateEngine()
def configContent = engine.createTemplate(templateContent)
    .make(placeholders)
    .toString()
    .replaceAll('\\\\\\\$', '\\\$')

println configContent
```

Output:

```
<?php
$my_php_config_variable = "SOME_VALUE"
?>
```

There is a bug report [GROOVY-8701](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-8701) documenting this issue. One of the future releases of Groovy 2.5.x should contain a fix for that so there is no replacing `\$` with `$` needed anymore.

Alternatively you can use `GStringTemplateEngine` - in this case no replacing escape character needed:

```
import groovy.text.GStringTemplateEngine

def placeholders = [
  "StreamingTemplateEnginePlaceholder": "SOME_VALUE",
]
def templateContent = new File('test.php.template').text

def engine = new GStringTemplateEngine()
def configContent = engine.createTemplate(templateContent)
    .make(placeholders)
    .toString()

println configContent
```

Output:

```
<?php
$my_php_config_variable = "SOME_VALUE"
?>
```

Comment: Thx a lot for your hints! I already tried to escape the $ sign of the PHP var but - as you mentioned too - ended up with also escaped $ signs in the rendered string.
The GString Engine indeed works as we need it.
In which case should one prefer the StreamingTemplateEngine to the GStringEngine?

Comment: @T0mcat Check http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/template-engines.html#_template_framework for Groovy template engines comparison. `StreamingTemplateEngine` should be considered if your template is larger than 64K

Comment: Thx again! I'll check this.

Comment: Using the `StreamingTemplateEngine` here for strings >64k. For the `replaceAll` you have to remove one "\" each (`replaceAll("\\\\\\$", "\\$")`). Otherwise you get a compilation error: `Invalid character constant`